# Can i print the instance of has_object_permission?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm trying to create REST API with django-rest-framework. My question is can I print the instance of `has_object_permission` method so I can see what is going on in that part. I'm trying that only the owner of an object can update and delete the object but right now anyone can delete or update anybody object. Please tell if there is other way to do besides permissions. Can we do all these with checks in serializer. If yes then please guide me that too with example. I shall be very thankful.

```
class ObjectOwnerPermission(BasePermission):

    message = "This object is expired." # custom error message

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return True
        return False

        if obj.author == request.user:
            return True
        return False


class RetrieveUpdateProjectAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView,ObjectOwnerPermission):
    """This endpoint allows for updating a specific Project by passing in the id of the 
Project to update/Retrieve"""
    permissions_classes = [ObjectOwnerPermission]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer

class DeleteProjectAPIView(generics.DestroyAPIView,ObjectOwnerPermission):
    """This endpoint allows for deletion of a specific Project from the database"""
    permissions_classes = [ObjectOwnerPermission]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions dont work because your return `True` in your `ObjectOwnerPermission` when user is authenticated which means that ANYONE who is authenticated can pass this permission.

**EDIT:**
In the original question `permissionS_classes` whas used instead of `permission_classes`

Here is my fixed version:

```
class ObjectOwnerPermission(BasePermission):

    message = "This object is expired." # custom error message

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):    
        return obj.author == request.user


class RetrieveUpdateProjectAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """This endpoint allows for updating a specific Project by passing in the id of the 
Project to update/Retrieve"""
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ObjectOwnerPermission]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer

class DeleteProjectAPIView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    """This endpoint allows for deletion of a specific Project from the database"""
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ObjectOwnerPermission]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer
```

- DONT inherit from permission class in your views - it should be only used in `permission_classes`
- if you want to chain your permission, it should be implemented in `permission_classes` list
- permission classes are read from left to right which means that `IsAuthenticated` is checked first before your class (in your class you are sure that user is logged in)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time and response and I updated the code in my project but still, any user can update or delete any object. permission check isn't working I guess

Comment: Oh, bad word is used.. it should be `permission_classes` no `permissionS_classes`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect brother!.  It worked smoothly. I really appreciate.

Comment: Brother what if anyone can retrieve the object but only the owner can update the object. Right now only the owner can see his project and update that.

Comment: You can check `action.name` in `has_object_permission` and use current statement for `destroy` `update` and `partial_update` actions else return True eg. `if view.action in ('destroy', 'update', 'partial_update'): return obj.author == request.user`

Comment: Nice but it says that **'RetrieveUpdateProjectAPIView' object has no attribute 'action'**

Comment: Hmm so i guess you need to use `viewsets.GenericViewSet` class with some mixins `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` and `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` instead of (`generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView` and `generics.DestroyAPIView`). Define one `class ProjectAPIViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, ...mixinclasses)` with same parameters like in previous views and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238849/discussion-between-dummy-first-and-mon-io).